# Can not load an image from url using Picasso?

Tags: android, firebase, picasso

I am trying to load an image using Picasso but nothing renders.

The idea of the code is to choose an image from the device. Later we upload it to the server and show it to the user.

First two parts are implemented, but the problem is image doesn't show in the corresponding image view.

Here is layout file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:text="Select image"
      />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b_img"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button bSelectImg;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private static final int g_img = 1;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {....

        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        bSelectImg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_img);
        imageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profileImage);

        bSelectImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
         intent.setType("image/*");
         startActivityForResult(intent , g_img);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

        if(requestCode == g_img && requestCode != RESULT_OK ) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            progressDialog.setMessage("uploading.....");
            progressDialog.show();

            StorageReference filepath = storageReference.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

            filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Task<Uri> downloadUrl = storageReference.getDownloadUrl();

                    Log.i("urlimagexcx",""+downloadUrl);

                    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                            .load(downloadUrl.toString())
                            .into(imageView);

                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Upload is don",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  progressDialog.dismiss();
             }
           });
        }
    }
}
```

In the app level gradle file, I am using Picasso version 2.5.2-

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
   // implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'


/// 
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem is because you are not retrieving the url properly.
After you upload the image inside the onSuccess try doing this instead:

```
        filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(final Uri uri) {
                                String downloadUrl = uri.toString();

                               Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                               .load(downloadUrl)
                               .into(imageView);
                            //continue closing brackets here...
```

Upon further inspection i have noticed that your onActivityResult may also have a problem.
This does not seem right to me.

```
   if(requestCode == g_img && requestCode != RESULT_OK )
```

Instead it should be:

```
   if(requestCode == g_img && resultCode == RESULT_OK )
```